# Reading from a memory pointer (base address)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dll

I just started digging into C++ Yesterday after watching around 7+ hours of tutorials on game hacking, however my goal is not to create a hack for a game at all, however to see if I can create an automated system or a (BOT) to do things for me. This is simply for a learning experience, however.

Currently I understand how to get the Base-Pointers, what multi-level pointers are, and how to write to memory, however I have yet to find any decent information on reading from memory that I could get to work.

For this project I am using a DLL that is being Injected into the software that I am using. I am wanting to gather some data from the memory. I've taken the time to find the static pointers for some of the variables that I am wanting to display on my Windows Application Form. (Such as the health, etc)

```
The Base Pointer for one of these variables is: 0x302DD0E8
The Offset for the base pointer is: 0x84C
```

After experimenting quite a bit and doing hours of research I have come up with this code

```
DWORD HPValue = *(DWORD*)(*(DWORD*)0x302DD0E8 + 0x84C);
```

However, this instantly crashes my application, if I remove this code and inject the DLL everything works fine.. well "Works" as it's not really doing anything besides sitting there.

Really looking for help understanding how this works, I'm not trying to do anything bad like ruin a game either, just trying to get some experience in. Here's a screenshot of what my DLL Interface looks like, I'm literally just trying to read data.

http://gyazo.com/0b60c4246a8bd7ebc8da3620ad311eb4

Here's a picture of the address information as found in cheat-engine, this information works on other computers as-well as I have tested since asking this question.

http://gyazo.com/733d50c751119376d3195b6a5b703e9a

When I say I have the pointer, what I mean is I have the base address, I've already cycled through all of the pointers to get the base address.....

Comment: I suspect the biggest thing you'll have a problem with here is [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). That means there's no guarantee that whatever bit of data you're reading is going to be in the same place next time you run your game. And in particular, there's no guarantee that the base/offset that somebody else came up with is going to be the same for your computer, regardless of ASLR. You might also consider visiting https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: pointers to memory have a limited lifetime. If those pointers are to objects on the heap, then they are essentially random each time you run the program.  Pointers to the stack are useless outside of the running application, even if they aren't random, because they are overwritten immediately after a function returns. You can't hard code the hexadecimal addresses in your code, you need a way of determining them at run time.

Comment: @GregHewgill - I've tested this pointer after game restarts and computer restarts, it pulls the same information, I just don't know how to do it with C++ --- I think they call this a "Base Address"? Sorry, I'm still kind-of new to it all, however it's the variable that people nuse when making trainers for games etc.

Comment: Assume for a moment that 0x302DD0E8 is a valid memory location with data at it. `*(DWORD*)0x302DD0E8` This casts 0x302DD0E8 to a DWORD pointer and then the outside * (dereference) says get the DWORD at that location. Then whatever DWORD value is AT that location has 0x84C added to it. I doubt that was what you wanted

Comment: I assume what you want is to add 0x302DD0E8 to 0x84C then you simply want to get the DWORD value at that location and store it in HPValue. I think what you want is `DWORD HPValue = *(DWORD *)(0x302DD0E8 + 0x84c);`

Comment: Run your code in an IDE(eclipse for example - CDT) and debug it. you would be able to see at each step what is happening in your registers, memory, assemlby

Comment: @MichaelPetch - This is returning some strange value, while the pointer+offsets in my other program are returning the correct value (seen here: http://gyazo.com/733d50c751119376d3195b6a5b703e9a )